# IEEEtrantools clash with cleveref

Tags: equations, ieeetran, cleveref, option-clash

I have two rather complex equations I would like to align at the two points to the left and to the right of the '=' sign.

Elsewhere in the document I am using `cleveref`'s `\cref` command, but that package clashes with `IEEEtrantools`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
   a & = & 3\\
   b & = & 4
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Further would I like to give these two equations one tag, that should be displayed right-aligned and vertically centred.

I took the equations from a book (Bohren and Huffman, 2004) and would like to keep both, their numbering and their formatting, which looks like this:

[image: taken from Bohren & Hoffmann, 2004, p. 100]

How can this be achieved, with `cleveref` being kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `cleveref` that has not taken into account some changes made to `IEEEtrantools.sty`. In particular, the conditional `\if@IEEEissubequation` is not any more in the package. The patches made by `cleveref` refer to version 1.2 of `IEEEtrantools`, but you probably have version 1.3 (2012/12/27).

You can try by adding some code that will avoid the error:

```
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\let\if@IEEEissubequation\iffalse
\makeatother
```

However, I'm not certain this won't have strange consequences.

As far as centering a unique number for the two equations, I believe this is not covered by `IEEEeqnarray`, but `aligned` of `amsmath` will do:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b \\
c & = d
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I think that you *can* load both `amsmath` and `IEEEtrantools`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of the packages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} 
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  & \begin{array}{rcl}
   a & = & 3\\
   b & = & 4
  \end{array}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

However, it makes more sense to use the `amsmath` package and then the `align` environments.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
   a & =  3\\
   b & =  4
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Reversing the package load order is wrong. It might avoid the compilation error in this MWE, but it completely disables cleveref's IEEEtrantools support and risks producing nonsense cross-references (without any warning!)

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility with newer versions of `IEEEtrantools` should be fixed in the latest pre-release version (0.21) available from my web site: http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.html